# height of div is not filling 100% body height

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar a header and a main container. main container and header is nested inside a parent div. When I set height 100% for both sidebar and main container the sidebar doesn't take 100% of the height of the body. I was thinking to not use any percentage values and let flexbox do the work. But I suspect that as I append elements inside the main container area sidebar will behave the same and not take the height of the body space. How can I fix this?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar-container {
  background-color: #00ffff;
  width: fit-content;
}

.header_main {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100vw;
}

.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: bisque;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-container">sidebar</div>
</div>
<div class="header_main">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="main">main</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `body` has no height specified. So what do you expect *100% of body* to be? Also, **none of your elements uses `height: 100%`**.

Comment: I tried specifying min-height: 100% to the body but it still behaves the same :)

Comment: how do I get sidebar to take 100% of the body height and not leave any space unfilled

Comment: `height: 100%` means 100% of the parents height. That however requires the parent to actually have a defined height. By default the height is unset and calculated to `fit-content`. So 100% of unset/undefined is what?

Comment: Why are you setting `.header_main` to `position: absolute`?

Comment: I see `.main` having the `100vh` height you specified. So, what is the problem here?

Comment: @gre_gor I think that it overflows by default and the sidebar is not filling the entire body height,

Comment: @tacoshy yes exactly!

Comment: Because `100vh` + header height > `100vh`. And for a similar reason there is also horizontal overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use CSS-Grid. Then simply set the body as grid-container and give it a `min-height: 100vh`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto;
}

aside {
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: #00ffff;
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
}

header {
  background-color: pink;
}

main {
  background-color: bisque;
}
```

```html
<aside>Sidebar</aside>
<header>Header</header>
<main>Main</main>
```

Comment: That's really helpful. Thanks! I also didn't know there was a asisde tag that is used to create sidebars.